# Prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}y\sin(1/x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}y\sin(1/x)=0$

We know that $|\sin(1/x)|\leq1$

We need to prove for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$, $|y\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$ when $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$.

We can look at this intuitively, if $y=mx$ , $y\sin(1/x)=mx\sin(1/x)$. The limit can only exist if $x\sin(1/x)=0$ at $0$.

Since $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ , $0<y<\sqrt{\delta^2-x^2}$. So $0<y\sin|1/x|<\sqrt{\delta^2-x^2}\sin|1/x|$. I don't know how to proceed further, please help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Sandwich Lemma for functions of several variables?

Comment: To beginners: the statement in this question, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}y\sin(1/x)=0$, is an essentially step for the problem in the linked "duplicate", which asks about the continuity of a multivariable function at the point $(0,0)$. Nevertheless, note that they are two different statements.

Comment: @LouisPan: "Duplicate" (in the MSE context) does not mean the same question, it means that the/a solution given to one problem also provides a solution for the other.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks for your comment. The point of my message above is for users who have yet to learn the notion of continuity for multivariable functions. You are right that the essential step in the linked one can solve the problem here. But I was simply saying that these two questions are not mathematically identical.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation of $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$ should have almost had everything done. Simply note that
$$
0\le |y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
.$$

So if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon$, then
$$
0\le |y\sin(1/x)|\le |y|<\epsilon.
$$